# Convert STEP file type to STL

Tags: step, stl-format, freecad

I want to convert a STEP file into an STL file format using Python. I have looked online and it looks like the best option is to either use FreeCAD or OpenCascade (OCC). However, I am a beginner and do not know where to start from. I did some search online and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865401/how-to-convert-an-uploaded-step-file-to-other-formats) out (a code to convert STEP to OBJ file).

Are there any python examples from FreeCAD (based on OCC) to convert STEP files to STL? Where should I start?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a quick bit of code to start out:

```
import FreeCAD
import Part
import Mesh
shape = Part.Shape()
shape.read('my_shape.step')
doc = App.newDocument('Doc')
pf = doc.addObject("Part::Feature","MyShape")
pf.Shape = shape
Mesh.export([pf], 'my_shape.stl')
```

FreeCAD uses python extensively for user-facing functions.  Basically, anything you do through the UI is done with python.

So it's useful to open up the UI, open up the Python console, and then do a function manually.  You can often just copy the python directly from the console and edited it to serve your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a complete beginner in this stream. Is it possible to download the FreeCAD, Part and Mesh libraries using pip and run and IDLE script? How do I proceed on making a standalone python script for this?

Comment: Not with Pip.  The Mesh and Part libraries are installed with FreeCAD and should be in the system Path.  So the above script should work as a standalone python script.  See this page for more: https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Embedding_FreeCAD

Comment: I was able to convert STEP to STL file format. However, I am running into a problem converting Collada (.dae) to STL. I have noticed that FreeCAD software lets you import file in .dae and save it as .stl format. However, I can't find any code for that. Do you know of a way I can accomplish that?

Comment: I tested by importing a .dae and exporting an .stl and it worked fine.  I did have to manually install pycollada first.

Comment: In the above code you gave I tried to import .dae file by replacing shape.read('my_shape.step') by shape.read('my_shape.dae') (and I have a my_shape.dae file in the same directory). I have also installed pycollada ind imported that module (import collada). However, I get the error at 
shape.read('my_shape.dae') file that 


"shape.read('wolf.dae') Base.FreeCADError: {'sclassname': 'N4Base13FileExceptionE', 'sErrMsg': 'Unknown extension', 'sfile': '', 'iline': 0, 'sfunction': '', 'swhat': '', 'btranslatable': False, 'breported': True, 'filename': ''}"

Comment: So basically the error tells me "Unknown extension". Can you let me know what environment you are using (version of FreeCAD, pycollada, python etc.). Are there any other modifications I need to make in the code above? Shape.read always gives an error of unsupported format.

Comment: I have posted this question in the link given below. If you can answer it there, I can choose it as the accepted answer
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836264/freecad-shape-read-error-unsupported-format

Comment: More information on FreeCAD: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76665637/coding-library-to-convert-step-to-stl-without-large-output-file-sizes. In this post, a link is included to a set up and debugging on FreeCAD.