# Convert .OBJ file to STL using FreeCAD python

Tags: stl-format, freecad

I have been working on a project to convert CAD files from different formats (OBJ, FBX, COLLADA, 3DS, IGES, STEP, VRML/X3D) to STL. Recently, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714806/convert-step-file-type-to-stl/55732964#55732964)
question on stackoverflow to convert STEP file to STL format and was successfully  able to do so. Right now, I am working on converting an OBJ file to STL format using FREECAD and Python. Are there any python examples to convert OBJ to STL so that I know where to start and how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer online. More details can be found by referencing [this](https://github.com/faerietree/freecad_convert/blob/96c416f4bf3f317fc73701400864b5f2741e19e0/freecad_convert.py) script. The short answer is:

```
Mesh.open("inputFileName.obj")
o = FreeCAD.getDocument("Unnamed").findObjects()[0]
Mesh.export([o], "outputFileName.stl")
```

Answer (score 1):

FreeCAD exports all settings
All the settings of FreeCAD, all in the FreeCAD folder.

`C:\Users\a←When` installing the operating system, the name `entered.\AppData←File Manager` ~ “Hidden project” to open, the AppData folder will be displayed.\Roaming\FreeCAD

Back up the FreeCAD folder, when reinstalling, put the FreeCAD folder in its original place.

Note: To clear all settings, just delete the FreeCAD folder, then open the program, a new FreeCAD folder will be created.

FreeCAD exports toolbars and macros I made
Common path
`C:\Users\a←When` installing the operating system, the name entered.`\AppData←File Manager ~ “Hidden project”` to open, the AppData folder will be displayed`.\Roaming\FreeCAD\Please` take the branch path below.

Branch path

```
\FreeCAD\user.cfg←The “toolbar” I made is placed here.

\FreeCAD\Macro←The “Macro” I made is placed here.
```

Back up the file and folder, when reinstalling, put the file and folder in its original place.

Record settings with screenshots
In the event that there is no way to export the settings, Record settings with a screenshot, It is the best way.

For example: Desktop location, toolbar location, and more...

Record settings with a screenshot, When reinstalling, It will be restored soon.

The same is true for mobile phones.